# How to restore non-renewable subscription purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Apple StoreKit does not automatically restore "non-renewable subscription" products between devices.

However, Apple policy does require that the app manually restore non-renewable subscription products between the users devices.

The question is, what user data can I use to uniquely identify the "same user" between devices?

I suppose I can use the iTunes email, is it possible to access that within the public API?